# .NET - First chance exception listener for intensive debugging?

Tags: .net, debugging, exception, first-chance-exception

This is probably unrealistic, but would it be possible to enable a component to be notified of all first chance exceptions occuring in its process?

We have some third-party (contracted by us) components which fail to do anything but eat excepitions and the politics of the business relationship make the whole ordeal a royal pain.

We also are aware that some of our code is performing the disappointing action of letting exceptions vanish into the abyss rather than using our centralized exception logger.

I assume our application would have to be started as a child process of a debugging application to achieve the effect, but I figure it's worth asking :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Net 4.0 has actually added the [`AppDomain.FirstChanceException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception.aspx) event. It fires before any catch block is executed.

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997368.aspx) has some examples.

Basically you just add an event handler like this:

```
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += 
        (object source, FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FirstChanceException event raised in {0}: {1}",
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName, e.Exception.Message);
        };
```

Comment: Very nice find!  Thanks much for dusting off this old question!

Answer (score 7):

You can use the .net profiling API to get notifications of exceptions at all sorts of states, these are the available methods:

```
ExceptionThrown
ExceptionSearchFunctionEnter
ExceptionSearchFunctionLeave
ExceptionSearchFilterEnter
ExceptionSearchFilterLeave
ExceptionSearchCatcherFound
ExceptionOSHandlerEnter
ExceptionOSHandlerLeave
ExceptionUnwindFunctionEnter
ExceptionUnwindFunctionLeave
ExceptionUnwindFinallyEnter
ExceptionUnwindFinallyLeave
ExceptionCatcherEnter
ExceptionCatcherLeave
ExceptionCLRCatcherFound
ExceptionCLRCatcherExecute
```

Using the profiling api is not entirely for the faint of heart; have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404386.aspx as an entry point for your research and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384687.aspx for exception handling specifically.

I'm not aware of a simple way to do it within your managed code such as

```
AppDomain.FirstChanceException += new EventHandler...
```

event or similar.

EDIT: A possibly better alternative is using the [unamanaged debugging API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404520.aspx) instead.

Basically you can set a [ICorManagedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms232496.aspx)/[ICorManagedCallback2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms232530.aspx) callback using [ICorDebug::SetManagedHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms232544.aspx) and get callbacks when exceptions occur.

I'm not experienced enough in this area to know what the advantages/disadvantages are over the profiling api.

I just had a look at the [mdgb sample](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=38449a42-6b7a-4e28-80ce-c55645ab1310&displaylang=en) which uses the ICorDebug APIs and it seems to get quite enough notifications from exceptions (to quickly see what events occur, set a breakpoint in the HandleEvent method in corapi/Debugger.cs:406)

Comment: I didn't expect it to be easy, but an in-road is all I need to at least get a feel for it.  Thanks much!

Comment: I edited my answer as after playing around with mdbg, I believe possibly the ICorDebug API might be a better way to do it.