# Determine if code called from an exception handler (using statement)?

Tags: .net, exception, using, finally

I want to do something mildly silly. In my `Dispose()` method for an object, I want to print a debug trace for the object, telling me all events which happened while it was alive.

But as this takes time and money, I only want to do this if `Dispose()` is being called because an exception was thrown.

So I would like to do

```
if (exceptionIsCurrentlyRaised) PrintDebugStuff();
```

Does .NET have such a exceptionIsCurrentlyRaised property which I can query?

Comment: I doubt that you can arbitrarily keep track of all "events" that happen to an object. If you want to keep track just put logging into the object that logs what you need every time methods are called.

Comment: I do my own logging of events that interest me, but that's not the question I'm asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine if executing in finally block due to exception being thrown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301507/determine-if-executing-in-finally-block-due-to-exception-being-thrown)

Comment: Yeah and also duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815492/how-to-determine-whether-a-net-exception-is-being-handled which has some more interesting answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if anything like this exists as I have never seen it. But it sounds like you could just create an interface that has a single bool property. Then when you are inside the catch statement but before you call the dispose method just set the flag.

I'm guessing it can't be this easy of a solution but thought I would get some ideas started.

EDIT: Ok I also found this SO article that has a similar problem: [Determine if executing in finally block due to exception being thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301507/determine-if-executing-in-finally-block-due-to-exception-being-thrown)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, but I doubt that this is possible - at least not without some major hacking using debugging or profiling APIs.

Even if you were able to call some debugging API that could give you access to the current exception inside a `catch` block I don't think you could get the exception inside a `finally` block (which is where your `Dispose` method would be executed). By then the exception may have been handled, so, as far as the runtime is concerned, there is no exception.

The only way I can see if doing this is to register to be notified of *all* exceptions since your object was constructed and from there try to figure out whether the exception was caught or not. This answer may be helpful: [.NET - First chance exception listener for intensive debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952304/net-first-chance-exception-listener-for-intensive-debugging/952360#952360)

Comment: If the exception was handled and not rethrown, there would indeed be no exception while the 'finally' block was running.  On the other hand, a common scenario is for finally blocks to run while an exception is being thrown to an outer scope.  If a finally block is trying to do something like a transaction rollback and it fails, it should throw a rollback-failure exception with the pending exception as an InnerException.  Unfortunately, there's no clean way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is something like the "IntelliTrace" feature of Visual Studio 2010, which can record what happened during a debugging session when you were *not* at a breakpoint.

Comment: A good obvservation. Is it possible to make use of intellitrace without using VS though?

Comment: I really don't know. I haven't gotten into it yet.